# IE 10 does not load page in UTF-8

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, internet-explorer-10

I've got simple HTML pages in Russian with a bit of js in it. 
Every browser going well except IE10. Even IE9 is fine. Next code is included:

```
<html lang="ru">
<meta http-equiv="Cоntent-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
```

Also I've added .htacess with

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Still IE10 loads page in Cyrillic encoding (cp-1251 I believe), the only way to display characters in a right way is to manually change it to UTF-8 inside of a browser (or chose auto-detect mode).

I don't understand why IE10 force load 1251 instead of UTF-8.

The website to check is http://btlabs.ru

Comment: Please place the meta after (inside) `<head>`. The rest was already corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What really causes the problem is that the HTTP headers sent by the server include

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
```

This overrides any `meta` tags. You should of course fix the errors with the `meta` tag as pointed out in other answers, and run a markup validator to check your code, but to fix the actual problem, you need to fix the `.htaccess` file. Without seeing the file and other server-side issues, it is impossible to tell how to fix that (e.g., server settings might prevent the effect of a per-directory `.htaccess` file and apply one global file set by the server admin). Note that the file name must have two c's, not one (`.htaccess`, not `.htacess').

You can check what headers are e.g. using Rex Swain’s [HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/cgi-bin/httpview.cgi).

The reason why things work on other browsers is that they apply the modern HTML5 principle “BOM wins them all”. That is, an HTTP header wins a `meta` tag in specifying the character encoding, but if the actual data begins with three bytes that constitute the UTF-8 encoded form of the Byte Order Mark (BOM), then, no matter what, the data will be interpreted as UTF-8 encoded. For some unknown reason, IE 10 does not do that (and neither does IE 11).

But this won’t be a problem if you just make the server send an HTTP header that declares UTF-8.

If the server has been set to declare windows-1251 and you cannot possibly change that, then you just need to live with it. Transcode your HTML files to windows-1251 then, and declare windows-1251 in a `meta` tag. This means that if you need any characters outside the limited repertoire representable in windows-1251, you need to represent them using character references.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot changing `cоntent=text/html;` to `cоntent="text/html";`

As Shawn has already pointed out, it could also be `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`.

But as you have tried both things out, can you confirm if the IE10 output looks like [this](http://minus.com/i/bNUZkmHvoWnc)?

I can't really help further with this, as the only thing I have here is an IE 10 online emulator.

**So far the possible problems are:**

- [Different `o` character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20661875/2569639)
- I see, that the [`<meta>` tag is still outside of `<head>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661785/ie-10-does-not-load-page-in-utf-8/20661837#comment30934938_20661785), put it in place
- Problems with IE handling the content and charset attributes

Comment: Edited. IE10 still going wrong :( tried both `<meta http-equiv="Cоntent-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` and `<meta charset="utf-8">` - same result.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps because your 'o' in 'content' is not an ascii 'o'. notice that it is not red in Stackoverflow? i then copied it to a good text editor and see that it is indeed not an o. because the 'o' is not really an ascii 'o', that whole line probably should get ignored in every web browser, which should then depend on what default charset it uses. Microsoft and IE is notorious for picking bad defaults, thus is my reason why it doesn't work in IE. ;)

but codingaround has good advice too. it's best to put quotes around your attribute values. but that should not break a web browser.

you should use a doctype at the start:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

but the real culprit is your content and charset problem. notice my line. mine is very different. ;) that's the problem. note that mine has *two* ascii 'o's, one in "Content-Type" and another in 'content='.

Comment: Edited. Thanks to SO for lightning, working now in a notepad, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: hmm, i'll play around a bit with it.

Comment: i edited my answer. note there is no such thing as the charset attribute on the meta element in HTML 4. 'charset' is part of the value of the 'content' attribute: `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: but in HTML 5 they added a charset attribute that stands alone, without the 'http-equiv' attribute. Microsoft is notorious for messing up when everything is not exactly one way or the other. the other browsers are more forgiving that IE.

Comment: Shawn is correct with the 'o' problem. You fixed one 'o' but not the other 'o'. You still need to fix the 'o' in "Content-Type".

Answer (score 1):

As Shawn pointed out, copy and paste this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

This is a really good example of how non-Ascii letters that look like English Ascii letters can really mess things up!

Comment: And Joop is correct. Your `meta` element should be inside your `head` element.